# How to Evaluate the Java syntax using Apache JEXL

Tags: java, apache, jexl

I tried to use JEXL to evaluate the syntax but not getting through.
Want your help guys to get it executed.

I want to evaluate dynamic replace statement (.replace("\u00A0","")) coming through ajax.

In Java -

```
removeSpecialChars = ".replace("\u00A0","");
text.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
text = text + removeSpecialChars;
```

How can we evaluate the **text** statement using JEXL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow [JEXL's tutorial](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/examples.html#Evaluating_Expressions)

> The easiest way of obtaining a a context is to use the new MapContext() statement. This creates a context implemented using an underlying HashMap
>
> Expressions are created using the JexlEngine.createExpression(String) method.
>
> Once you have your expression, you can then use use the evaluate to execute it and obtain a result.